# How do I not pay out of my wallet?

Tags: steam

I've got some money in my wallet, but not enough to pay to for the game I want. I'd rather keep my money in my wallet and pay the entire amount with other funds.

However, in the checkout, as soon as I've made the choice that I want the game for me! me! me!, I'm asked to choose how to pay the *remaining* amount. Where did the option go to pay everything with my card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to go back. Using the back button will bring you to a page you've skipped automatically, where you can choose to pay everything by other means.